# How to show on a Trello card the date that the card was added to a board?

Tags: trello

Is it possible to show "date added" on a Trello card? Via custom fields perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with a [Custom Fields](https://blog.trello.com/trello-custom-fields) PowerUp

[image]