# How to sort Trello cards by date added

Tags: trello, sorting, date

Trello is rad. But one thing I haven't figured out:

How to sort cards in a list by the date that the cards were added to the list (or to the board)?

Also, is it possible to show (as a custom field?) the date that a card was added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trello support [tells me](https://twitter.com/trellosupport/status/829467666951856128):

> This isn't possible natively, but there's a popular Chrome extension that does allow for this: [Ultimello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm/related?hl=en-US)

I've since downloaded the extension, and it seems to do the job. How it works:

> You can sort the cards by Due Date, Title (Alphabetically), Votes, Labels, and Creation Date. *The Apply current sorting* menu item will save the current sorting in Trello, which means that current cards order will become the actual cards positions.

**The one thing missing:** an indication (custom field?) on the card for when it was added to a list. Without this, it isn't obvious to users of the board that the list is now sorted chronologically.

Give an answer to [this related question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99633/13351) if you know how to implement this functionality.

Comment: I use this extension too, and it's super useful especially with the sorting.  The developer Yuriy is helpful too with new features and questions.  Recommend it!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Butler for Trello](https://www.butlerfortrello.com), which is a bot that automates Trello (I'm the author). This command:

`sort list "X" by time in list`

sorts a list by the length of time that a card has been in the list. You can also reverse it:

`sort list "X" by time in list descending`

You can apply the command at certain times, e.g.:

`every day at 6am, sort list "X" by time in list`

Or when something happens to the list:

`when a card is added to list "X", sort the list by time in list`

With regards to displaying the creation date, you could issue a command like this:

`when a card is created, rename it to "{cardname} (created on {date})"`

This appends the creation date to the title. You could instead add it to the description or as a comment. Custom field writing support is not yet available because of limitations in the Trello API that Trello have committed to solve.